PowerAutomate Desktop - SAP Automation
I'm trying to use PowerAutomate Desktop to logon to SAP GUI.
I have enabled scripting and able to show the logon screen, but unable to actually log on to SAP GUI.
Here is the error I receive:

Correlation Id: 2adffa1b-7f21-4b88-aa80-6631e24a7d1d

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.: Microsoft.PowerPlatform.PowerAutomate.Desktop.Actions.SDK.ActionException: Action failed. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.SAP.Actions.SapLogin.Execute(ActionContext context)
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Modules.SAP.Actions.SapLogin.Execute(ActionContext context)
  at Microsoft.Flow.RPA.Desktop.Robin.Engine.Execution.ActionRunner.Run(IActionStatement statement, Dictionary`2 inputArguments, Dictionary`2 outputArguments)


